# Is there any code issue in this python file?

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oy0x0.png)I am trying to download batch images using the attached python file but when I run it, it shows this error how it can be resolved?
Thanks

```
from google_images_download import google_images_download   
response = google_images_download.googleimagesdownload()  

search_queries = ['Fan' , 'Mouse' ,'Phone','Chair','Bottle'] 

def downloadimages(query): 
    arguments = {"keywords": query, 
                 "format": "jpg", 
                 "limit":200, 
                 "print_urls":True, 
                 "size": 300*300, 
                 "aspect_ratio":"wide"} 
    try: 
        response.download(arguments) 

    # Handling File NotFound Error     
    except FileNotFoundError:  
        arguments = {"keywords": query, 
                     "format": "jpg", 
                     "limit":4, 
                     "print_urls":True,  
                     "size": "medium"} 
        try: 
           response.download(arguments)  
        except: 
            pass
for query in search_queries: 
    downloadimages(query)  
    print()
```

[,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGyVV.png)

Comment: Need more information. The error message is being reported on line 52 of a script of which you've only pasted 29 lines.

Comment: `"size": 300*300` in python is equivalent to `"size": 90000`

Answer (score 1):

See the below list of choices for size and exact size and modify your code accordingly:

```
parser.add_argument('-s', '--size', help='image size', type=str, required=False,
                            choices=['large','medium','icon','>400*300','>640*480','>800*600','>1024*768','>2MP','>4MP','>6MP','>8MP','>10MP','>12MP','>15MP','>20MP','>40MP','>70MP'])

parser.add_argument('-es', '--exact_size', help='exact image resolution "WIDTH,HEIGHT"', type=str, required=False)
```

If you want image with 300*300 then you should use exact_size "300,300"

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to have any effect on the search.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://google-images-download.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arguments.html) the valid values for the size argument are:

```
Possible values: large, medium, icon, >400*300, >640*480, >800*600, >1024*768, >2MP, >4MP, >6MP, >8MP, >10MP, >12MP, >15MP, >20MP, >40MP, >70MP
```

Any other value will cause a KeyError.

PS: These values have to be passed as strings within quotes.